# How to design SSRS report to filter multi-value parameter?

Tags: filter, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, visibility, multivalue

I developed an RDL which takes a multivalue parameter and I want to set a visibility expression or filter based on this parameter.  This parameter uses an "All" value equal to '660E4583-7F29-4D37-8038-5096AE6A1A7F'.
I want to make the main tablix visible if this parameter is set to this uniqueidentifier and invisible otherwise.  How can I achieve this either in the tsql dataset or on the report side?  I have tried numerous workarounds, but none have worked so far!  I've tried different expressions and datatypes.
Before I tried If/Else statements in the tsql dataset, but most recently I instead added flags to the tsql dataset for each condition and am trying to make this tablix only include the records with the flag matching the parameters chosen.  But even this is not working for me.

Here is sample data:

```
create table #dummydata
(
parameter varchar(max),
b varchar(max)
)

insert #dummydata values('660E4583-7F29-4D37-8038-5096AE6A1A7F','record 1'),('660E4583-7F29-4D37-8038-5096AE6A1vcd','record 2'),('660E4583-7F29-4D37-8038-5096AE6A1v52','record 3')

select * from #dummydata
```

And my filter expression in the RDL for this tablix is:

```
=iif(Parameters!Modifier.Value(0)="660E4583-7F29-4D37-8038-5096AE6A1A7F",1,0)
```

With datatype = integer and value = 1
However, this tablix is invisible with the above even when I choose "All" for the parameter value = default value.  How can I make this tablix visible?

Comment: I am bit unclear about your question, still have you tried TRUE FALSE instead of 1 o. Is that expression defined on Hidden attribute/property of a tablix ?

Comment: I think Aditya is correct. Something like =iif(Parameters!Modifier.Value(0)="660E4583-7F29-4D37-8038-5096AE6A1A7F","True","False")